# Unable to Save data to Datastore using google appengine cloud endpoint libraries with android

Tags: java, google-cloud-endpoints

I have created an android project with an appengine backend. Appegine has one API saveTask.
This is working if i am directly triggering from the api explorer.

While triggering the same from android using cloud endpoint libraries, data is not getting saved to datastore. I am not getting any exception or error while executing the line

```
        SaveTask task = taskEndpoint.saveTask(newTask);
```

As there is no error i was not able to figure out whats going wrong.

Appengine Code

@ApiMethod(name="saveTask",path="task",httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)

```
public Task saveTask(final User user, TaskForm taskForm ) throws UnauthorizedException{

    //String id = "1";
    String taskName=taskForm.getTaskName();
    String taskDesc=taskForm.getTaskDesc();
    String createdUser=taskForm.getCreatedUser();
    String assignedUser=taskForm.getAssignedUser();
    Task task = null;
    Long id =taskForm.getId();


    if(id!=null){
        task = ofy().load().key(Key.create(Task.class,id)).now(); 
    }
    if(task ==null){
        task = new Task(taskName,taskDesc,createdUser,assignedUser);
    }else{
        task.update(taskName,taskDesc,createdUser,assignedUser);
    }
    ofy().save().entity(task).now();
    return task;
}
```

//Android Code

```
 public void saveTask(View view){
    TaskForm newTask = new TaskForm();
    EditText taskName =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.taskName);
    EditText taskDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.taskDesc);
    newTask.setTaskName(taskName.getText().toString());
    newTask.setTaskDesc(taskDesc.getText().toString());
    newTask.setCreatedUser("asdf");
    newTask.setAssignedUser("asdfasd");
    newTask.setId((long) 12345);

    TaskApi.Builder endpointBuilder  = new TaskApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), null);
    TaskApi taskEndpoint = endpointBuilder.build();

    try {
        SaveTask task = taskEndpoint.saveTask(newTask);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Task_View.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the server side code i.e. saveTask get called when you invoke it from Android ? Could you put in some log statements and outer exception block in your server side code to see what could be happening?